# What was the actual ancient way of doing Sandhya?

Tags: vedas, sandhyavandanam, smarta, vedanga, katyayana-srauta-sutra

We all know in the current Sandhyavandanam paddhatis that are available to us, contains many procedures or mantras that are from Puranas like the shuklam baradharam mantra or the apavatri pavitrova mantra. Also, the achaman with different names of Vishnu like Padmanabha or Madhusudana comes from Puranas. My question is what was the actual ancient Srauta way of doing Sandhya before the Puranas or Agamas were written? Is the ancient way of Sandhya written in any of GhryaSutras or the DharmaSutras or in any of 4 parts of Vedas or Vedangas?

Comment: Sandhyavandana covered in the parishisthas -texts which act as appendices to the grihyasutras.

Comment: @অনু Does those procedures exist even today? Does anyone follow that, do you have any scriptural references? What is the source of your information?

Comment: Ayushman it seems that you have very little understanding of sandhyavandana. Apart from Gayatri japa, sandhyavandana also consists of Brahmayajna & Suryopasthana, where Vaidika mantras are recited. The mantras recited vary according to the Veda followed by the brahmin. It is only achamana & some preliminary acts that invoke Pauranika deities. Otherwise Sadhyavandana is completely based on Shrauta texts.

Comment: @অনু I am sorry if you did not get me properly, I am aware of the fact of Vedic mantras in Sandhyavandanam, what I mean to ask is how were the preliminary acts such as achaman , asana suddhi or the pavitrikaran done before the puranas?